# Disable blending of UIView with its superview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics, blending

I am creating say a rectangle in coregraphics - using CGContext functions in the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method of **UIView** and adding it to a **superview**. When i change the background of the **superview** , the color of the **UIView** blends with it.
I want to disable this blending.

Comment: If you're filling your whole view then you can set its backgroundColor to [UiColor whiteColor]

Comment: @AbidHussain i found the solution. Its mentioned below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some exploration( QuartzDemo Code of Apple) i finally found the answer to my problem. The color of the UIView was filled using [UIcolor color with R:G:B:Alpha] and the alpha was not 1.0.

Also i used `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);`

Comment: `kCGBlendModeNormal` is the default, as implied by its name.